# install grub on another partition

Tags: 11.10, windows, grub2

hey i want to install Ubuntu 11.10 outside windows but i want that the  default boot loader to be used is window's one.also will it be possible to insert the boot location of ubuntu after removing grub into windows bootloader

Answer (score 1):

I believe that we are using grub2 so the process now can be done with grub-install /dev/hdx. Here's a link to the documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html